# Always got a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while trying run AutoML by java in H2O

Tags: java, h2o, automl

I'm using H2O 3.20.0.5 to train some models.

I want build model by using AutoML in my java code. Now I can import and parse csv file. But when I try to call `AutoML.startAutoML().get()`, I always got a j`ava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in ModelBuilder.java`.

It is seemed that there is no any ALGOBASES defined in `ModelBuilder`. But I'm using AutoML  which is supposed to create algorithm automatically. So I'm totally confused. Here are my codes:

```
private static void trainByAutoML(Frame frame, String projectName) throws FileNotFoundException {

    AutoMLBuildSpec autoMLBuildSpec = new AutoMLBuildSpec();

    autoMLBuildSpec.input_spec.training_frame = frame._key;
    autoMLBuildSpec.input_spec.response_column = "level";
    autoMLBuildSpec.input_spec.sort_metric = "AUTO";

    autoMLBuildSpec.build_control.balance_classes = true;
    autoMLBuildSpec.build_control.class_sampling_factors = new float[2];
    autoMLBuildSpec.build_control.class_sampling_factors[0] = 1.0f;
    autoMLBuildSpec.build_control.class_sampling_factors[1] = 1.0f;
    autoMLBuildSpec.build_control.nfolds = nfolds;
    autoMLBuildSpec.build_control.keep_cross_validation_models = false;
    autoMLBuildSpec.build_control.keep_cross_validation_predictions = true;
    autoMLBuildSpec.build_control.project_name = projectName;
    HyperSpaceSearchCriteria.RandomDiscreteValueSearchCriteria randomDiscreteValueSearchCriteria = new HyperSpaceSearchCriteria.RandomDiscreteValueSearchCriteria();
    randomDiscreteValueSearchCriteria.set_max_runtime_secs(Double.parseDouble(autoModelRuntimeSeconds));
    randomDiscreteValueSearchCriteria.set_stopping_metric(ScoreKeeper.StoppingMetric.AUTO);
    randomDiscreteValueSearchCriteria.set_stopping_tolerance(0.0);
    autoMLBuildSpec.build_control.stopping_criteria = randomDiscreteValueSearchCriteria;

    AutoMLBuildSpec.AutoMLBuildModels autoMLBuildModels = new AutoMLBuildSpec.AutoMLBuildModels();
    autoMLBuildModels.exclude_algos = new AutoML.algo[4];
    autoMLBuildModels.exclude_algos[0] = AutoML.algo.DRF;
    autoMLBuildModels.exclude_algos[1] = AutoML.algo.GBM;
    autoMLBuildModels.exclude_algos[2] = AutoML.algo.GLM;
    autoMLBuildModels.exclude_algos[3] = AutoML.algo.StackedEnsemble;

    autoMLBuildSpec.build_models = autoMLBuildModels;

    AutoML aml = AutoML.makeAutoML(Key.make(), new Date(), autoMLBuildSpec);
    AutoML.startAutoML(aml);
    AutoML.startAutoML(autoMLBuildSpec).get();
    aml.leader().getMojo().writeTo(new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/aaa/model_data/1.zip")));
}
```

I always got that exception when the code run into `AutoML.startAutoML(autoMLBuildSpec).get();`. Here are the stack trace of this exception:

```
08-31 02:38:53.583 127.0.0.1:54321       9246   FJ-1-15   ERRR: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
08-31 02:38:53.583 127.0.0.1:54321       9246   FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at hex.ModelBuilder.algoName(ModelBuilder.java:106)
08-31 02:38:53.583 127.0.0.1:54321       9246   FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at ai.h2o.automl.AutoML.trainModel(AutoML.java:519)
08-31 02:38:53.583 127.0.0.1:54321       9246   FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at ai.h2o.automl.AutoML.defaultDeepLearning(AutoML.java:808)
08-31 02:38:53.583 127.0.0.1:54321       9246   FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at ai.h2o.automl.AutoML.learn(AutoML.java:1058)
08-31 02:38:53.583 127.0.0.1:54321       9246   FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at ai.h2o.automl.AutoML.run(AutoML.java:369)
08-31 02:38:53.583 127.0.0.1:54321       9246   FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at ai.h2o.automl.H2OJob$1.compute2(H2OJob.java:32)
08-31 02:38:53.583 127.0.0.1:54321       9246   FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1267)
08-31 02:38:53.583 127.0.0.1:54321       9246   FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
08-31 02:38:53.583 127.0.0.1:54321       9246   FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
08-31 02:38:53.583 127.0.0.1:54321       9246   FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
08-31 02:38:53.583 127.0.0.1:54321       9246   FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
08-31 02:38:53.583 127.0.0.1:54321       9246   FJ-1-15   ERRR:     at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

Comment: Can you share the details how are you starting H2O? This looks like you skipped some of the startup sequence steps because the algos are not registered. H2O log would be very helpful in this case - it could show us what is missing.

Comment: I think you are right, I just use H2O.main(args); and H2O.waitForCloudSize(1, 10 * 1000); to start a h2o node, and then I just load the data. I didn't register any algos. So can you please tell me how to register algos? Thanks.

Comment: I just created a RegisterAlgos object and use its registerEndPoints method with an empty RestApiContext object as its parameter. Now It's working. Thanks a lot. But I'm not sure if this is a correct method to initialize AutoML in Java. It's hard to find document about this on H2O official site.

Comment: Maybe you can use H2OApp.main(..) or H2OStarter.start(...) if you need a finer control over how H2O is started. I would say that there should almost never be a need to call H2O.main(..) directly.